# Scanner/File Input not reading all characters

Tags: java

First post - Let me know if I have missed anything needed to help.

I am new to coding but I need to be able to read into the program via file and user input all keyboard characters. It sounds simple but when I enter '£' for example via scanner or reading from file it does not store the character. From what I have read it sounds like a character set issue but I am unsure how to change them.

This is the output of just the scanner reading nextLine() and printing

Enter the Password:

Test£

Test�

Exception is thrown when trying to read the character I think. At this line

```
  encrypted.append( vig2[longPass.charAt(i)][file.charAt(i)]);
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65533

The program works fine when I use just a text document with normal characters.

It does work with all characters when I have added an exception ect, but it does not read them, I need to accept all characters as I am trying to encode / decode files.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the full code, for example, what is stored in vig2, what are the lines above and below the problem statement

Comment: It sounds as if you use Vigenere Encryption and I assume you don't handle the possibility of an Overflow.
char is 2 Byte and if you add the password char and the char to exncrypt this may lead to an value bigger than what you can handle with 2 bytes. But you only have a dictionary for 2 bytes of possible characters.

Comment: Of course you can add the charset name as second parameter to the constructor of the Scanner.
For example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29